# What is the difference between AopTestUtils and AopProxyUtils?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-aop

What is the difference between AopTestUtils and AopProxyUtils?

As far as I understand, **AopTestUtils** calls **AopProxyUtils**.
But I didn't understand why it was needed then?
In which cases what should I use. I will be glad to have a detailed answer

Comment: Good question. I can assume that this is related to the contour you are working with. But I'm not sure about this answer.

Answer (score 0):

**AopTestUtils**
It is a collection of AOP-related utility methods for use in unit and integration testing scenarios.

---

**AopProxyUtils**
It provides utility methods for AOP proxy factories. Mainly for internal use within the AOP framework.

For more detailed information you can refer to the documentation
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/AopTestUtils.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/AopProxyUtils.html

Comment: That's the question. If you look into them, they do absolutely the same thing! And I don't understand why. If you look in the documentation they have the same description